# How to return two columns with function

Tags: sql, postgresql, set-returning-functions

I want to return 2 values with my SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_avg_prices(...)
  RETURNS table(avg_sale_price decimal, avg_rent_price decimal) 
AS
$$

SELECT 
  building_prices.avg_sale_price, 
  building_prices.avg_rent_price
FROM 
  ...

$$
  LANGUAGE sql;
```

It works but returns the values in single column:

[image]

How to return the values in 2 separate columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table functions (functions defined as `returns table` or `returns setof`) need to be used in the `from` clause like a table.

So you need to use:

```
select * 
from get_avg_prices(...);
```

Only scalar functions (functions which return only a single value, e.g. a number) should be put into the `select` list.